# Unable to copy "Install OS X Yosemite.app" file to my external hard drive

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I completed this process on my MacBook Air running Mavericks. From the App Store I clicked to download and upgrade to Yosemite. I stopped the process at a point where it downloads a 5.17 GB file named "Install OS X Yosemite.app" into app folder and will continue installation of it later.

Now I am trying to move this file to my Seagate portable hard drive with FAT32 format. When I try to copy and paste this app to the drive, it said the device (hard disk) didn't have enough space for this format, although my hard drive has 90GB empty space.

What should I do?

Basically I am asking how can I transfer this Yosemite.app file to another Mac for upgrading it from Mavericks to Yosemite, and not having to download it again and again.

Comment: My first question.  Are you using a supported hardware that CAN be upgraded?  But there are far to many grammatical and typographical errors for me to completely follow your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) can only store 4GB files. You need to do one of the following:

- Split the file into parts, then recombine it, using any split and combine tool (such as [Split&Concat](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9545/split-concat) or the [command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43583/howto-merge-files-after-using-split-command-from-terminal))
- Reformat your external hard drive to use another file system that OS X can write to, which in your case would be [exFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT) or HFS+. You can use *Disk Utility.app* under *Applications/Utilities* to do that.